# Web scraping for Linkedin

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, linkedin-api

I am currently working on a college project for Linkedin Web **Scraping** using selenium. Following is the code for the same:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from parsel import Selector

driver = webdriver.Chrome('location of web driver')
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

# username
username = driver.find_element_by_id('session_key')
username.send_keys('Linkedin Username')
sleep(0.5)

# password
password = driver.find_element_by_id('session_password')
password.send_keys('Linkedin Password')
sleep(0.5)

#submit value
sign_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="submit"]')
sign_in_button.click()
sleep(0.5)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')   #Navigate to google to search the profile

# locate search form by_name
search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

# send_keys() to simulate the search text key strokes
search_query.send_keys('https://www.linkedin.com/in/khushi-thakkar-906b56188/')
sleep(0.5)

search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(3)

# locate the first link
search_person = driver.find_element_by_class_name('yuRUbf')
search_person.click()

#Experience
experience = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#experience-section .pv-profile-section')
for item in experience:
    print(item.text)
    print("")

#Education
education = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#education-section .pv-profile-section')
for item in education:
    print(item.text)
    print("")

#Certification
certification = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#certifications-section .pv-profile-section')
for item in certification:
    print(item.text)
    print("")
```

When I scrape the experience part, it extracts the information perfectly. But when I do the same with Education and certifications part - It shows an empty list. Please help!

Comment: I guess you mean “scraping”  - i.e. getting data by reading it from HTML web pages - rather than “scrapping” - i.e. throwing away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem ís because of your css selector. I try it my self and it is unable to locate any element on html main body

Fix your css selector and you will be fine

```
#Education
education = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#education-section li')

#Certification
certification = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#certifications-section li')
```

Comment: Oh got it. Thank you so much.
Also, one more question. How do I scrape the other parts like - skills, recommendations, accomplishments ? I am not able to locate the correct correct css selector for that either.

Comment: Check two link i send you. It has very specific info about how to use xpath and css selector. You also can use some extension like Chropath to have help you identify you locator without needing to identify it manually. Practice for sometime and you will find it easy to identify locator.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working in LinkedIn scraping for a couple of weeks. The way that I could find all the information was as follows, you have to take into consideration how the HTML is constructed, analyze the ul and the li:

```py
target_element = soup.find('div',id='experience').findNext('div',class_='pvslist__outer-container')
lists = target_element.findAll('li',class_='artdeco-list__item')
```

Analyze how the id is displayed on the different sections of the HTML you want to scrape. Hope this helps.